# Laravel: accessing a resultset

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm very new to Laravel and I am trying to access an object I get successfully back from the database. Its a

> book

object and when I print it to screen with this line:

> {{{ $book or 'Default' }}}

I get back the object printed as so:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"Dress yourself like the Crabmeister","isbn":"18274827","publication_date":"14\/03\/1978","author_id":"1","genre_id":"4","available":"1","created_at":"1397346572","updated_at":"1397346572"}]
```

Although this is fine and proves successful, when i try to access just one attribute such as

> title

, it gives me an undefined exception. I try to access it with this line:

> $book->title

I'm sure its an obvious answer but any help appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: Is this a JSON-object?

Comment: Nope, Its an eloquent obj brought back from the db, also i feel silly but i just replaced my line $book->title with $book->get(0)->title and it worked. It seems resultsets must always be iterated through or at least treated like an array of objects even if its only one result

Comment: It depends on how you return your object. There are multiple ways with Laravel, maybe you should  put the model 'book' into your question too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you return your object. There are multiple ways with Laravel. 
Your returned Object seems to be a JSON-object.

Try the following in your view

```
<script>
    var book = '{{ $book }}';
    //...

window.console.log(book.title);
</script>
```

Or you don't return the book object as JSON and you access it in the view like this:

```
@foreach($book as $b)
    {{ $b->title }}
@endforeach
```

**Edit after comment**

Try to put the get() method at the end of your model's call (Just an example as I don't see your model):

```
$books = new Book();
return $books->where('something', '=', 'some other')->get();
```

Also, in your model, you can do

```
...->get()->toJson();
...->get()->toArray();
```

**Laravel Docs:**

- [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)
- [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)